# How to temporarilly pause loop

Tags: java, android-studio

I am making an APP which always is detecting noises. And when it detect a loud noise it starts a function.

While the function is happening I need temporarily pause the loop which detects noises.

How can I do that?

Hares my code:

```
private void readAudioBuffer() {

    try {
        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        int bufferReadResult;
        do {
            bufferReadResult = audio.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++){
                if (buffer[i] > lastLevel) {
                    lastLevel = buffer[i];
                }
            }
            // if sound level is over 20000 start voice recognition
            if (lastLevel > 20000){
                lastLevel = 0;
            // Pause this function:
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            }

        } while (bufferReadResult > 0 && audio.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: is 'startVoiceRecognitionActivity()' run in another thread?

Comment: I will update the code for you to see

Comment: sadly, I can't figure it out, but I think that probably somewhere, one of the methods such as startActivityForResult starts a new thread on which it processes the audio it hears, while letting your readAudioBuffer method run uninhibited

Comment: Why not to break the loop and start startVoiceRecognitionActivity after the loop?

Comment: I need after voice recognition for the loop to continue looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically adding 
Thread.sleep(5000);
Did the trick

```
    try {
        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        int bufferReadResult;
        do {


            bufferReadResult = audio.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++){
                if (buffer[i] > lastLevel) {
                    lastLevel = buffer[i];
                }
            }
            // if sound level is over 20000 start voice recognition
            if (lastLevel > 20000){
                lastLevel = 0;
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }

        } while (bufferReadResult > 0 && audio.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void readAudioBuffer() {

try {
    short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
    int bufferReadResult;
    do {
        while(audio.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING){
                //Wait for certain time. If it is in a recording state then it would enter this loop and wait else it would go ahead to check for sound levels.
           }
        bufferReadResult = audio.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++){
            if (buffer[i] > lastLevel) {
                lastLevel = buffer[i];
            }
        }
        // if sound level is over 20000 start voice recognition
        if (lastLevel > 20000){
            lastLevel = 0;
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }

    } while (bufferReadResult > 0);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it didn't work, but I found a solution that did